# How to filter out already selected image from images shown by `expo-image-picker`

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

I'm using `expo-image-picker` to select images from different folders. I works fine, but I want to filter out images that are already selected, in case user re-open the image picker to pick another image. In short I don't want user to pick same image more than once.

Comment: `expo-image-picker` doesn't provide a full API for that. You need to check if  image is existed and  before you upload it.

Comment: thanks @BYIRINGIRO Emmanuel